# How to translate "Is that what you think? That that is how the world works?"

Tags: translation

I would go for:

> "Ist das was du denkst? Dass das ist wie die Welt arbeitet?"

Comment: I wouldn't use the literal "arbeiten" for "work", something like "Dass das ist, wie die Welt funktioniert" conveys the meaning better.

Comment: I'd rather go for "Dass die Welt so funktioniert"?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could just shorten it and say:

> Ist das wie du denkst, dass die Welt funktioniert?

I don't think "arbeiten" is the right word to express what the sentence actually means.